# Use call back function to get pointer from a dependent class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two projects under one solution in VS2010.Project **Application** is dependent on project **Module**.

> I can't access application pointer in Module due to **dependency**.

But I know using a **callback function** I can get application pointer in Module.How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `extern` a pointer from `Module` in one of `Module`'s headers. Otherwise, you just call a function and return a pointer. Declare this function in a header and then call it from your application.